# Sapjco3.jar dependency gives an error in Spring boot project: It is not allowed to rename or repackage the original archive "sapjco3.jar"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dockerfile, github-actions

Our project repository was migrated to GitHub and we changed building an image
from jib-maven-plugin to using a Dockerfile and building it with GitHub actions.

In the former process the Sapjco3.jar library was added by giving an extra classpath.

```xml
<extraDirectories>
    <paths>
        <path>${project.basedir}/../some-module-name/lib</path>
    </paths>
</extraDirectories>
```

```xml
<extraClasspath>/sap/*</extraClasspath>
```

Because the application is now build through a Dockerfile this plugin had to be removed.
Instead of this the spring-boot-maven plugin is used to repackage the whole project into
one jar.

For this reason it would not be possible to do the same.

How do I get this .jar library into the final repackaged jar's BOOT-INF/lib folder?
It has to be this exact sapjco3.jar library because else it would give the error in the title.

Already tried:

- strip version
- custom layout
- maven-assembly-plugin
- maven-shade-plugin

I expect the project to run with the sapjco3.jar library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using the maven-jar-plugin to configure an extra Class-Path.
The extra classpath is relative to where the jar resides.
When buliding the docker image with a Dockerfile you can add the
library to this relative path.

The solution is thereby modifying the META-INF file.

**POM.xml**

```
<!-- Add classpath entry to the manifest -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Class-Path>lib/sap/sapjco3.jar</Class-Path>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
COPY ./{path-to-library}/lib/sap ./lib/sap
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a mavan dependency instead of `externaljar`?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
    <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.14</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Apparently there is a runtime check which checks the name of the jar. 
If this is changed or renamed it will give an error. 
ref : https://github.com/hibersap/hibersap/issues/26

Now if you use the maven dependency the spring-boot-maven plugin will append a version to this library in the /BOOT-INF/lib folder.

Comment: have you checked  in this way ? ... <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-cp</arg>
     <arg>${originalClassPath}${path.separator}${basedir}/../../../bin/POM_RUNTIME_PLACEHOLDER/JCOBridge.jar</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>    https://github.com/masesgroup/NuReflector/blob/master/src/NuReflector/defaultPOM.template